# Scroll content of 2 divs using single scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which has 3 rows. My code is in bootstrap. I want to put the horizontal scrollbar below the first row and above the remaining 2 rows i.e. between the first and second row. And when I scroll then content of all 3 rows should scroll simultaneously. How can I do that?
This is what I have tried so far

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="row sample_data">
        <div class="row sample_content">
            <div class="col-sm-4 graph_data_heading">Year</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 time1">Jan'16</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 time2">Feb'16</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 time3">Mar'16</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 time4">Apr'16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sample_content">
            <div class="col-sm-4 graph_data_heading">revenue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">230</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">287.5</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">359.375</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">449.21875</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sample_content">
            <div class="col-sm-4 graph_data_heading">Gross Margin</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">230</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">287.5</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">359.375</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">449.21875</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #main-content > .row > .row:first-child {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #main-content > .row > .row {
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
#main-content > .row [class*="col-lg"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-md"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-sm"] {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21349196/1398867

Comment: ok. But in this example 2 different div with 2 different scrollbar displayed. I just want to use single scrollbar displayed in between the first and second row inside a div.

Comment: the post suggested by  Venugopal would work. in addition to that, consider using css selector for the succeeding rows to hide their scrollbar

Comment: add `overflow: hidden` on 2nd and 3rd divs. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/sxP3m/14/)

Comment: I think this would work. I have to check. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `scrollLeft()` of `jQuery` change the scrolling position of 2nd and 3rd div.

sample code.

```
$('#top').scroll(function () {
    $('#bottom').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/sxP3m/15/)

Answer (score 0):

overflow:auto on the containing elements would be sufficient:

```
#main-content > .row{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#main-content > .row > .row{
  white-space: no-wrap;
}
```

Comment: scrollbar is not displayed in between the first and second row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class

```
#main-content > .row > .row:nth-child(2) {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```