# Flexbox/position scrolling discrepancy between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a `position:fixed` overlay, which I'm populating with navigation and content as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9871Lz1u/1/

I'm using flexbox inside a fixed position div, to control the positioning of my navigation buttons, and using a relative positioned div to house the content. Using Chrome, this works exactly as intended. Using Firefox/Safari (the latest builds) however, I find that when hovering my cursor over the flexbox (red and blue) regions, the scrolling is locked. I have to hover my cursor over the white content box to "enable" scrolling.

I'd like the Chrome behavior, allowing scroll no matter where the cursor is, to be the final consistent behavior. Further, I'd like the solution to be pure HTML/CSS, if possible.

My system: macOS Version 10.13.2, Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132, Firefox Version 58.0

```css
.container {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
 overflow: auto;
}

.nav-outer {
  position:fixed;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-inner {
  display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav-center {
  flex: 1 100%;
 order: 2;
 max-width: 400px;
}

.nav-container {
  flex: 1 auto;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 /* -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center; */
 align-items: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-left {
  order: 1;
  background: red;
}

.nav-right {
  order: 3;
  background: blue;
}

.nav-button {
  width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: black;
 display: block;
 z-index: 10;
 margin: auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 40px 40px;
 border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
    Some overflowable content<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-outer">
    <div class="nav-inner">
      <div class="nav-container nav-left">
        <div class="nav-button"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-center"></div>
      <div class="nav-container nav-right">
        <div class="nav-button"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure the output window in the fiddle is short enough that there's overflow, and wide enough that you can see the red/blue strips. Hovering your cursor over the colored strips while scrolling the scroll-wheel should scroll the content div in Chrome, but not in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way browsers handle this, is that they will scroll the element that has the cursor.

Even Chrome does, which you can see both in the *stack snippet* (when not in "Expanded mode"), where it will scroll the whole stackoverflow page if the cursor isn't over the scrollable text, and in the *fiddle*, if you start out the scroll on the red or blue element.

Chrome will however, if your first scroll the text, keep scrolling it, even after the cursor is moved to either red or blue element, and my guess is that it remembers that last scrolled, keep it the one that has *scroll focus*, until another element gets the focus.

So with the existing markup you will need a script to accomplish that, and here is one sample, making use of jQuery:

- [Scroll a div while using the scrollwheel over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347821/scroll-a-div-while-using-the-scrollwheel-over-another-div)

---

With a markup change, you can get away w/o the need of script, by simply drop the `container`.

This will have no impact on the layout, since the `body` more or less have the exact same behavior the fixed `container` has, hence it will be the `body` that will scroll, and that will work cross browser.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9871Lz1u/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nav-outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav-center {
  flex: 1 100%;
  order: 2;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.nav-container {
  flex: 1 auto;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /* -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center; */
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-left {
  order: 1;
  background: red;
}

.nav-right {
  order: 3;
  background: blue;
}

.nav-button {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/> Some overflowable content
  <br/>
</div>
<div class="nav-outer">
  <div class="nav-inner">
    <div class="nav-container nav-left">
      <div class="nav-button"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-center"></div>
    <div class="nav-container nav-right">
      <div class="nav-button"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You first recommendation did the trick. I was hoping I could get away with out binding any scroll wheel events, but no such luck. (As I mentioned in my question, this is all happening in a modal overlay, so the fixed container is necessary). Further, if anyone is using React, as I am, I ended up doing `onWheel = {this.onWheel.bind(this)}` on the `nav-outer` element, and then using `e.deltaY` to manually adjust the scroll position of the `content` element.