# Scroll two elements simultaneously - Prevent event on scroll

Tags: jquery

I'd like to prevent the first function from executing if it's the second event that cause the first to fire.

```js
$('.mygrid').on('scroll', function () {
  $('.mygridheading').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
    
$('.mygridheading').on('scroll', function () {        
  $('.mygrid').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] ?

Comment: the heading is on top of the matrix (times on Y axis, dates on X axis). It's basically a calendar and the heading is at the top and each column is a day.

Comment: I've simplified the code a bit. Basically, if A causes B to scroll, I don't want B to cause A to scroll

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong here, but cannot say exactly since I cannot visualize anything from your code so far - besides knowing that yeah, when you trigger a scroll of one, the scroll Event of that same will trigger recursively for the other one... ad absurdum.

Comment: I 100% agree with you, hence my desire to prevent one from triggering the other. This code still works, (i.e. if user scrolls the header, it scrolls the matrix). The only noticable downside is that it adds lagginess to the scrolling due to the extra processing. Aside from that, it works perfect.

Comment: Oh, than I'm right! Thanks for clarifying. Quite an interesting issue though!

Comment: no worries at all. thanks  :)

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling to a parent container. I don't know about jQuery, but I am assuming the first argument in your handler is an Event? (Also, maybe learning a bit of bog-standard JS is more helpful here, like `querySelector` and `addEventListener`.)

Comment: @somethinghere there's not a single reason in modern web development to use Event.stopPropagation(). An App should **always** be aware of all the propagating events. Both your own scripts and 3rd party scripts out of your control.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's very nice, but simply untrue. It exists for a reason. You can prevent this scroll event from firing on the parent if you want to capture it. It's usually best with preventing default, but in this case it can solve the problem. Which is what it is for.

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for the discussion. mygrid is not the parent of mygridheading, unfortunately.

Comment: @rokocbuljan Sure, sample size one. Your ideology over what perfectly fine parts of a language to not use is not really the issue here.

Comment: @somethinghere I just recurred since you mentioned  `stopPropagation`. You're right - it's not the issue and you can forget about `stopPropagation` even exists. Well - unless you really know what you're doing. And this problem is not the rare case to use one.

Comment: I'll have to agree with roko on this one since he was the only one to post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The issue***: Your elements "scroll" Events are **recursively** calling each other.

***Some possible Solutions***:

Remember the element which last received a `"mouseenter"` - that's clearly the only candidate to have *eventually* a Scroll Event attached to it:

```js
const $el = $(".scrollX");
let EL;

$el.on({
  mouseenter() { EL = this },
  scroll() { $el.not(EL).scrollLeft(EL.scrollLeft) }
});
```

```css
.scrollX {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollX" id="a">
  <p style="width: 300vw">Hold SHIFT and scroll</p>
</div>
    
<div class="scrollX" id="b">
  <p style="width: 300vw">This example should prevent recursive scroll event triggers</p>
</div>
    
<div class="scrollX" id="c">
  <p style="width: 300vw">Hold SHIFT and scroll</p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

Or -

Capture the `x` scroll value, and wait for a *"next tick"* using `setTimeout`.

```js
const $el = $(".scrollX");
let x = 0;

$el.on("scroll", function(ev) {
  x = this.scrollLeft;
  setTimeout(() => {
    $el.not(this).scrollLeft(x);
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
.scrollX {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollX">
  <p style="width: 300vw">Hold SHIFT and scroll</p>
</div>
<div class="scrollX">
  <p style="width: 300vw">This example should prevent recursive scroll event triggers</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this in the next hour.

Comment: @JasonHoward It's late hour - I'll review this one tomorrow for a cleaner solution since I don't like that awful `setTimeout` - "works" but it's kind of a hack.

Comment: Thanks Roko! I'd appreciate that very much. Have a good sleep and we'll chat tomorrow.

Comment: @JasonHoward posted another really simple and nifty solution without the odd `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks roko! I might have to go with the second one as this a problem related to mobile use and there is no mousetrap on mobile

Comment: @JasonHoward mouseenter is as a "fallabck" for touchstart on mobile - so I think you can use even the first one without problems. Otherwise you can always create a Event.touches check and define if mouseenter or touchstart should be used.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what holding shift does in the examples though. THe behavior is the same for me regardless of whether I hold shift.

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: @JasonHoward I'm on Windows, in order to scroll horizontally (on a regular mouse) you can do it by holding Shift key :)